# ppa and System Security

Tags: security, ppa, system, malware

I have been installing all my software from the Ubuntu Software Center. Recently, I had been installing software from PPAs. Can adding PPAs and installing software from them compromise the security of a computer system? And how likely is a Linux system to be infected?

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, yes. Adding PPAs and installing software *can* decrease the security posture of a systems. In general, you should only add PPAs that you know are reputable and well established or trusted.

How likely is a Linux system to be infected? *Not too likely.*

Answer (score 0):

I would say anything is possible which is why I recommend backups! :-D

From my personal experience I can safely say that I've added numerous PPAs to my systems for well-known and desirable software and never had a security breach AFAIK. The worst thing I've ever seen happen to an Ubuntu system was a home page hijack. Easily solved by setting the homepage back to normal. I would say of the dozen or more operating systems I have used Ubuntu is probably the least likely to become infected of them all. If I thought otherwise I'd be using something else.

Comment: I'm just desperate to earn as many badges as you senior StackExch folks! ;) Fingers-a-fire!